# Java Jolt copy properties with condition

Tags: java, json, jolt

I would like to transform flat data to array with conditional value of properties:

My input:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "myProp": true,
    "myAnother": true,
    "myAnotherOne": false
  }
}
```

My desired output:

```json
{
  "values": ["MY_PROP", "MY_ANOTHER"]
}
```

I think to use *shift* operation in order to normalize the name camelCase to ENUM standard.
I need to put in array only properties that are *true* in their value.

I tried many different options with no success.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: "best" is opinionated, please show what you have tried and what problems you have gotten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a **shift** transformation spec along with matching the key name **`true`** with **`$1`** wildcard coming from the inner object to provide the conditional logic such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "true": {
            "$1": "values"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

If the style(*converting the componenets of the array to uppercase and adding an underscore*) matters, then use a prolonged version of the spec like

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "true": {
            "$1": "val"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=toUpper(@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=split('MY', @(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "1": "&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "#MY_": "&1",
          "@": "&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=join('', @(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "values[]"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider this library "Josson & Jossons".

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
implementation 'com.octomix.josson:josson:1.3.22'

---------------------------------------------

Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{\n" +
    "  \"data\": {\n" +
    "    \"myProp\": true,\n" +
    "    \"myAnother\": true,\n" +
    "    \"myAnotherOne\": false\n" +
    "  }\n" +
    "}");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "map(values: data.entries().[value]*.key.upperSnakeCase())");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output:

```
{
  "values" : [ "MY_PROP", "MY_ANOTHER" ]
}
```